# How to hide the shell script in Blue Ocean page in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-blueocean

I have so many steps in under a stage.
Whenever I am using sh command, It is getting extra step with print of +sh command.
I want to avoid sh command step and print also.

1.)tried set +x, it is disabling prints inside step and but not step.
and +set +x is getting print.
2.) tried making returnstatus=false and returnStdout=false while using sh command